# SWIG Python binding for std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Service>> results in invalid pointer error

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am trying to use SWIG to generate Python bindings for a C++ project. The project includes a class InterfaceServiceManager with a method requestServiceByType that returns a std::vectorstd::shared_ptr<Service>.

Here is the relevant part of the InterfaceServiceManager class:

```
class InterfaceServiceManager{
public:
    virtual std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Service>> requestServiceByType(const std::string& service_type);
    // Other methods...
};
```

I have a SWIG interface file (test.i) that includes the necessary typemaps and includes for std::string, std::shared_ptr, std::vector, and std_map. Here is the relevant part of the SWIG interface file:

```
%module test
%include <std_string.i>
%include "std_shared_ptr.i"
%include "std_vector.i"
%include <std_map.i>
%include pointer.i 
%include typemaps.i 

// Other includes and code...

%shared_ptr(Service);
%shared_ptr(Endpoint);
%shared_ptr(Subscription);

%template(ServiceSharedPtr) std::shared_ptr<Service>;
%template(ServiceVectorSharedPtr) std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Service>>;
```

In Python, I am trying to call the requestServiceByType method like this:

```
import test
client_manager = test.Client_ServiceManager("Test")
listOfServices = client_manager.requestServiceByType("TestPoint")
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
<test.ServiceSharedPtr; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::shared_ptr< Service > *' at 0x7efcf0a8abe0> >
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted
```

It seems like SWIG does not know how to handle the std::vectorstd::shared_ptr<Service> return type. How can I tell SWIG to correctly handle this type? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Needs a `%template(ServiceVector) std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Service>`. Make a [mcve] if it still doesn’t work.